# Can you help clarify Javascript prototype inheritance method invocation?

Tags: javascript

In this block of code:

```
var Fruit = function() {}

Fruit.prototype = {
    color: function () {
        console.log('Fruit color...')
    }
}

var Apple = function () {}

Apple.prototype = new Fruit()
Apple.prototype.constructor = Apple

var a = new Apple()
Apple.prototype = null // the question!!!
a.color()
```

When `Apple.prototype` has been set to `null`, why can the instance `a` still invoke the `color` method?

Answer (score 9):

You're changing the `Apple.prototype` reference **after** you have created the instance `a`.

Changing the reference here doesn't change it for existing instances.

You'll also find

```
var a = new Apple();
Apple.prototype = {}; // some other object
a instanceof Apple; // false
```

i.e. because we've changed the inheritance chain of *Apple* `a` is no longer considered an *Apple*.

Setting `Foo.prototype = null` will cause a *TypeError* if you attempt to to an `instanceof Foo` check

---

Changing a *property* of an *Object* doesn't change the *reference* to that *Object*. e.g.

```
var foo = {},
    bar = foo;
foo.hello = 'world';
foo === bar; // true
```

Changing the *Object* itself does change the reference

```
foo = {hello: 'world'};
foo === bar; // false
```

Or written in a way more closely to how the prototype is referenced from an instance,

```
var Foo = {}, // pseudo constructor
    bar = {},
    baz = {};
var fizz = {}; // fizz will be our pseudo instance

Foo.bar = bar;          // pseudo prototype
fizz.inherit = foo.bar; // pseudo inheritance
Foo.bar = baz;          // pseudo new prototype
fizz.inherit === foo.bar; // false, instance inheritance points elsewhere
```

---

Current best practice for setting up an inheritance chain is not to use `new`, but to use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```
Apple.prototype = Object.create(Fruit.prototype);
```

If you need the `Fruit` constructor called on *Apple* instances, you would do

```
function Apple() {
    // this instanceof Apple
    Fruit.apply(this);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: yes, as we know, if we add `Apple.prototype` some method, such as `Apple.prototype.smell = function(){...}`, it will change the existing instances. but we change `Apple.prototype` value, will doesn't change the instances. so does the instances and `Apple.prototype` are reference the same object, then when change `Apple.prototype` value will not effect the object and no effect the instances?

Comment: @huang.xinghui—adding methods to the prototype doesn't change the instances, the method is made available to instances via the `[[prototype]]` chain. Perhaps read some articles on property resolution and prototype chains.

Comment: @RobG you may misunderstand, i add the method before set `Apple.prototype` to `null`. like this `var a = new Apple(); Apple.prototype.smell = function () {console.log('Apple smell...')}; Apple.prototype = null // the question!!! a.smell()`

Answer (score 0):

We have to understand what happen behind the line

```
var a = new Apple();
```

JavaScript adopts Prototype-based programming as its OOP style. That means, it creates a new object by cloning a former object, not by instancing a class. Given Gecko and Webkit JavaScript engines, here is what happen behind the "new" statement above:

```
var a = clone(Apple.prototype); // this is an analogy to memcpy() in C/C++
a.__proto__ = Apple.prototype; // useful for the instanceof checking
a.constructor = Apple; // a function
a.constructor(); // so "this" in the called function means "a"
```

So now, both *a.color* and *Apple.prototype.color* are references to the same function located at address, e.g., *0xABCD* because the value *0xABCD* was copied from *Apple.prototype* to *a*. Thus, calling *a.color()* will associate with the address *0xABCD*, it has nothing to do with *Apple.prototype*, so you can freely assign *Apple.prototype* to null.

It turns out that the *clone()* function above is actually the well-known *Object.create()* function. *Object.create()* also includes the assignment for the *__proto__* property.

Comment: It does not clone the prototype, it stores a reference to it. (As long as a reference exists it won't be GC'd so it will stay even if the original reference is destroyed)